# PgAdmin4: column-related problem in PostgreSQL after performing the copy command

Tags: postgresql, copy, command

**Two copy command syntaxes were tried, and the corresponding errors are shown below:**

**1.**

COPY smartphones(brand_name, model, price, rating, has_5g, has_nfc, has_ir_blaster, processor_brand, num_cores, processor_speed,battery_capacity, fast_charging_available, fast_charging, ram_capacity, internal_memory, screen_size, refresh_rate, num_rear_cameras, num_front_cameras, os, primary_camera_rear, primary_camera_front, extended_memory_available, extended_upto, resolution_width, resolution_height)from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data\data_copy\smartphones.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;

**ERROR:  column "brand_name" of relation "smartphones" does not exist [It exist in Reality]**

**2.**

COPY smartphones from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data\data_copy\smartphones.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;

**ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY smartphones, line 2: "oneplus,OnePlus 11 5G,54999,89, TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,snapdragon,8,3.2,5000,1,100,12,256,6.7,120,3,1,androi..."**

I failed to retrieve a CSV file with 26 columns in PostgreSQL. The error "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR: 'columns' when trying to import a csv file through pgAdmin4" was encountered when the import function was used similarly. I was unable to locate any appropriate solution online, so is there a way to solve this issue? If so, could you please offer your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. No it doesn't. You can trust PostgreSQL on that point.

Either you aren't connected to the right database / looking at the right schema or some such, or (and this is most likely), you created the table quoted and the column is called "Brand_Name" with capitals or something like that. If you (or the tools you use) quote identifiers you probably want to quote them all the time.

Google "sql case folding" for details.

2. You have more than 26 comma-separated items on that line and only 26 columns to put them into.

This is almost certainly because the file is not a correct CSV file. Check the line carefully there will be an unquoted value with a comma in it.

Answer (score 0):

COPY is unable to generate a table for you, so it won't function.
That must be completed before you can copy it.

**This problem now begs a new query. Is there a method for a table to be generated automatically in PostgreSQL when using the copy or import functions?**

Comment: This is no answer, but a comment / extra question attached to the OP